# WPF - Adding a Rowheader to a ListView Grid View

Tags: wpf, gridview, listview, wpf-controls

I need to add a rowheader to a Listview GridView. it needs to act like a datagrid rowheader, sop it should be freezable.

is thsi possible? can anyone show me some source code to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GridView do not have rowheaders but you can style the first column differently than the rest. Implementing freezing will require some innovative use of a scrollviewer. Can't you just use the DataGrid which has RowHeaders?

[DataGrid Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189753.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Wall street. I implemented a Row Header in a list view and it was pretty hard to get it looking right but its all done now.